# Check with ghostscript whether a PDF has transparent objects

Tags: pdf, transparency, ghostscript, pdf-parsing

PDFs can define transparency in several parts (see eg [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pdfnet-sdk/Ke75f9qBGYc)):

As graphical style attributes:

- fill opacity (`/ca`) or stroke opacities (`/CA`) below a value of 1.0
- definition of a soft mask (`\SMask`)

or with the definition of a transparency page group (`/S /Transparency`).

The following `grep` expression is a quick (and dirty) check for that:

```
grep -aE -e '/[Cc][Aa] +0?\.[0-9]' -e '/SMask' -e '/S /Transparency' *.pdf
```

Is it possible to check whether there are transparent objects with `gs`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe pdf_info.ps (gs/toolbin) will tell you this. Ghostscript wants to know in advance if a page uses transparency or not because it can do optimisations for performance and memory if it knows there is no transparency.

Note that a large number of PDF files floating about declare 'spurious' transparency where the transparency turns out to be 100% opaque :-(

Comment: how to use pdf_info.ps ? Can you please guide. I want to list all the transparent object in pdf document.

Comment: From the header of pdf_info.ps :  "% Dump some info from a PDF file

% usage: gs -dNODISPLAY -q -sFile=____.pdf [-dDumpMediaSizes] [-dDumpFontsUsed [-dShowEmbeddedFonts] ] toolbin/pdf_info.ps
" Obviously -sFile= should be the full path and file specification to the PDF file you are interested in. Depending where you run GS from you may need to modify the path to pdf_info.ps

Comment: Have been looking for a solution to check a PDF for transparency for 2 years now.. This works just perfect `gs -dNODISPLAY -q -sFile=input.pdf /var/bin/ghostscript-9.16/toolbin/pdf_info.ps` :D

Comment: @KenS can the pdf_info.ps code be updated to detect transparency object that are not 100% opaque ? basically remove the false positives because some pdfwriters are sloppy but out of the users control ?

Comment: In theory, yes, in practice, no. The amount of 'stuff' that would need to be checked is too great. For example you would have to look at every sample of a softmask image to see if its is anything other than fully opaque. Every ExtGState would have to be tracked to see if it is used or just pointlessly lying about. Every page would have to have every marking operation checked to see if it uses transparency, to validate whether a page Group was pointless, and the same for Form XObjects. And so on and so on. It would take longer to do the checking than is saved by not doing transparency.